# Algorithm to find the smallest integer m which when divides n distinct integers leaves distinct remainders

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

As the title says, I need an algorithm to find the smallest integer m which when divides n distinct integers leaves distinct remainders.

I know m has to be atleast n and further such an m always exist (m = max(all integers) + 1), but I don't understand how to proceed with finding the smallest m. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you provide some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: I don't know the answer but can suggest search terms. For a set of n numbers you are trying to find the smallest m where no two numbers in the set are congruent modulo m

Comment: What are constraints on `n` and maximum integer value? And/or what is the desired time complexity?

Comment: Try to implement and share some brute force approach. This basic solution can help you think of better solution.

Comment: For every pair of numbers a and b (where a is greater) in your set of n numbers, a and b are congruent modulo (a - b). They are also congruent modulo every factor of a  - b. For example 238 and 138 give the same remainder when divided by 100, and they also do when divided by 50, 25, 20, 10, 5, 4 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest approach is just to try it.

```
def distribute_remainders (numbers):
    m = len(numbers)
    while True:
        is_used = set()
        for x in numbers:
            if x % m in is_used:
                break
            else:
                is_used.add(x % m)
        if len(numbers) == len(is_used):
            return m
        else:
            m += 1
```

Testing remainders for a given number takes `O(n)`.  On average, it only takes `log(n)` tries until you run across a prime that will certainly work.  So on average this is no worse than `O(n log(n))` and probably is better.

What about a worst case? https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html says that a guaranteed upper bound to the next prime is still being improved, but the best records are around `O(n^0.535)`.  So worst case is `O(n^1.535)` and probably is closer to `O(n^1.5)`.

By contrast if we try to be clever, there are `O(n^2)` gaps to look at.  So we do worse than the very unlikely worst case before we've even enumerated them.

Comment: Not sure if I would characterise the gap approach as "clever." Maybe "risk-averse" :)

Comment: Thanks! I was unsure about the number of tries taken to find such a m, so was reluctant to go for this approach...but if it takes log(n) on average, it's nice!

Comment: @Ridayesh I was sadly wrong. One of the gaps can be divisible by any number of other numbers. But even so, I'm pretty sure that just trying them is faster than trying to factor gaps.

Answer (score 2):

If we imagine the list sorted, we have numbers at a variety of distances from each other:

```
a     b    c      d  e    f...
 <---> <--> ...
 <--------> <-------> ...
       <---------> ...
       ...
```

To duplicate a remainder, one of those distances must be `m` or a multiple of `m`.

One possible solution is to start `m` at 2; and create a set of all divisors of all the distances, incrementing `m` by 1 every time one of the divisors matches it.

For example,

```
[2, 6, 8, 14]

m = 2

Distance   Divisors      m
4          4, 2          3
6          6, 2, 3       5
12         12, 6, 3, 2   5
2          2             5
8          8, 4, 2       5
6          6, 2, 3       5


Remainders mod 5:
[2, 1, 3, 4]
```